# How to navigate to directory which file system object has just been moved to?

Tags: command-line, bash

I often find when using `mv somefile somepath` I often need to go to the location which the file had just been moved to.

basically  `mv somefile somepath && cd somepath`

is there a way to accomplish this without using multiple commands?

Answer (score 2):

How about defining a custom `bash` function to do the job :

```
move () { mv -- "$1" "$2"; cd -- "$_"; }
```

put this `move` function at the end of your `~/.bashrc` file.

- Run the function as `move somefile somepath`
- `$1` is the first argument to the function (`somefile`)
- `$2` is the second argument (`somepath`)
- `$_` expands to the last argument of the previous command (`$2` in this case)

**Example :**

```
/foo$ move () { mv -- "$1" "$2"; cd -- "$_"; }

/foo$ ls -1
bar
spam1
spam2

/foo$ move spam* bar/

/foo/bar$
```

As you can see the desired files have been moved and the directory is also changed accordingly.

Comment: Added to my `.zshrc` :)

Answer (score 0):

other than combining commands as you did the only other way would be to cd to the directory where you want to be in first then:

```
~/Documents$ mv ~/Desktop/somefile ~/Documents
```

Comment: which would be two commands